# Filtering rows by a list and sum values

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, filter

I have a `df`

```
    ID       Count_     Sum       AA     BB        dist
0       3     0.0        50.0   300.0    0.0  100.000000
1       7     0.0        40.0   700.0    0.0  141.421356
2    4983     0.0         0.0   500.0  200.0    0.000000
3    4982     0.0         0.0   400.0  200.0    0.000000
4    4984     0.0        30.0   600.0  200.0  100.000000
5    4981     0.0         0.0   300.0  200.0    0.000000
6    4985     0.0        40.0   700.0  200.0  141.421356
```

And two lists

```
List1 = [3,4983,4984]
List2 = [7,4981,4985]
```

Both lists are generated by some other code. And let's say in this case `List1` is generated by `id=5` and `List2` is generated by `id=18`.
I'd like to create a new df like this

```
     id      sum_dist
0       5     200.0        
1       18    282.84
```

Where new column `sum_dist` is created by sum all values in column `dist`, filter by `List1` or `List2`. For example - for `id=5` we look at `List1` and filter all rows in `df` that have this values in column `ID` and `sum`() values in `dist` column.

I have a problem writing a general solution, so I'd be able to work on larger df's. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first get that id column into your df. Something like:

```
df['id'] = None
df.loc[df['ID'].isin(List1),'id'] = 5
df.loc[df['ID'].isin(List2),'id'] = 18
```

Then you can do the last step with a `.groupby`

```
df.groupby(by = 'id')['dist'].agg('sum')
```

If you want to generalize further, I'd start by putting the lists into a dictionary with the ids. This will make the above code easier in a loop:

```
lists = {5: [3,4983,4984],
         18: [7,4981,4985]}
```

Hope that helps!

EDIT: Fixed a bug with the .loc function.

Comment: Thanks! But I have a problem with the first part - adding a new column to df. This works for having List1 and List2. What if i'd have more lists?

Comment: Solved. I simply used `for` loop. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ummm check with

```
from collections import ChainMap
mapdict = dict(ChainMap(*map(dict.fromkeys, [[3,4983,4984],[7,4981,4985]],[5,18])))


df.dist.groupby(df.ID.map(mapdict)).sum()
Out[8]: 
ID
5.0     200.000000
18.0    282.842712
Name: dist, dtype: float64
```